# Unable to access CSS of sibling <a> elements in unordered list

Tags: jquery, css, properties

I have a jQuery script that is working well for the most part. I have a list of links that I click on to show/hide specific DIV elements. When I click on a link it's CSS altered (color of link changes to red).

**HTML**

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li><a href="#" class="review-link" name="review-1">Click to see Review 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="review-link" name="review-2">Click to see Review 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="review-link" name="review-3">Click to see Review 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".review-link").click(function () {
  var divname = this.name;
  $("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
  $(this).css("color","red");
  $(this).siblings().css("color","green")
});
```

What I am having trouble doing is having all the **other** links reset to their original color. In my example I am trying to turn all the other links to the color green but I cannot even get that to work. Perhaps I am not understanding the "sibling" property in jQuery?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webworm/uCS3P/1/) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.review-link` elements have no siblings. You want its parent element's siblings.

You could use something like this instead...

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find("a").css("color","green")
```

Comment: I think I see. The <a> doesn't have the siblings, but the containing <li> element does?

Answer (score 3):

In the `onclick` event set all the links to that original color before you do anything else.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".review-link").css("color","green")
    $(".review-link").click(function () {
      var _this=$(this);            
       _this.closest("ul").find(".review-link").css("color","green");
       //your remaining code goes here
    });
});
```

working sample http://jsfiddle.net/uCS3P/5/

Comment: Great idea. I didn't even think about first setting them all to green.

Answer (score 1):

`$.siblings()` looks for directly related elements. In this case, `$(this)` is referring to the `<a>` element that was clicked, and since each link is nested within an `<li>` tag, it has no direct siblings.

`$(this).parent().siblings().find('a').css("color","green");`

or

`$(this).parent().siblings().children('a').css("color","green");`

will work.

You might want to look at using addClass and removeClass instead of changing the css directly with jQuery, it keeps the separation of markup and scripting more intact.